# How to show in app notifications in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I have created a screen specifically for notifications and I want the notifications to come inside that screen.

I know how to make push notifications via OneSignal or FCM but they are just notification apear on the notification bar or the lock screen that's it and even the local notification flutter is also the same it just comes once in the notification bar of the phone or the lock screen but what I want is the notifications should be inside the app with the text and the image or only just the text at least written visible later on when user opens the app.

This is pretty common in apps we generally use like facebook, twitter but I am wondering there is no any information availble on the internet.

Comment: You have to make an overlay. Here's a package: overlay_support

Comment: Have you ever done work with overlay_support? If yes then please share any example the package itself is very hard to understand

Comment: @MaxMoe this question has nothing to do with flutter. your backend sever already has those notification data before sending it to your phone. you can use simple REST API to retrieve those data from the server (for which notification has been sent) and display it in to your screen.

Comment: `showSimpleNotification(
        Text("this is a message from simple notification"),
        background: Colors.green);
}` Already have an example.